# Expo app crashing in production because of unknown error

Tags: android, react-native, google-maps, expo, react-native-maps

I've build an app in React Native/Expo that is working fine in development, but the android version crashes in production. Upon opening, the splash screen renders and then the app crashes.

I've tried running  `expo start --no-dev --minify` to replicate the app in production, and the app has worked fine. It's proving hard to debug because there aren't really any logs for me to inspect, the only useful piece of information I've found is from my google play console where I'm getting the error:

> :com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@230815033@23.08.15 (150300-0) - com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.drd.p.a
> java.lang.RuntimeException

Does anyone know what this error means, or does anyone have any suggestions on how I can debug this?